# Set text style to the top of Google Docs page

Tags: google-docs

In Microsoft Word you can set a style to be placed at the top of the next page.
Can I do the same with Google Docs?

Let say you have this text and the **titles style** are set to be at the top of the page. Then the  **Title 2** line text is automatically moved to the top of the next page.

> **Title 1**
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
>   Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque
>   penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
>   Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque.
>
> **Title 2**
>
> Lorem ipsum
>   dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula
>   eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
>   parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies
>   nec, pellentesque.

Comment: You don't have to keep removing tag words from the title if they've already been included as a natural part of the question title @pnu